# Convert Columns to Row keeping First Column Data Intact

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was able to use 'Text to Columns' and separate a comma delimited text to Columns. Is there a way to now transpose columns to rows keeping Column A on each row.

Here's what I have:

```
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    CABLE    KECL    SCOOTER     SELLIND     TI  UCO
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    KECL      CABLE   SCOOTER     SELLIND     TI      UCO
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:20 am    CABLE    SCOOTER     SELLIND     TI  UCO    
Fri Nov 25 2022, 9:25 am    CABLE     HMT     SCOOTER     TI      UCO
```

Here's what I am trying to achieve

```
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    CABLE
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    KECL
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    SCOOTER
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    SELLIND
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    TI
Tue Nov 29 2022, 9:20 am    UCO
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    KECL
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    CABLE
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    SCOOTER
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    SELLIND
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    TI
Mon Nov 28 2022, 9:50 am    UCO
..and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test1()
    Dim rng As Range, a As Variant, cnt As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        a = rng
        cnt = 0
        ReDim out(1 To UBound(a, 1) * UBound(a, 2), 1 To 2)
        For r = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            For c = 2 To UBound(a, 2)
                If Not IsEmpty(a(r, c)) Then
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    out(cnt, 1) = a(r, 1)
                    out(cnt, 2) = a(r, c)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        rng.ClearContents
        rng(1).Resize(cnt, 2) = out
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]